# Clojurescript core.matrix aljabr implementation must be explicitly set

Tags: clojurescript, clojurescript-javascript-interop

Using [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix/) in a ClojureScript project. For javascript interop I need [aljabr](https://github.com/originrose/aljabr) as explained in https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix/wiki/Matrix-implementations

After I try to specify the implementation (as I do with other Clojure implementations)

```
(require '[clojure.core.matrix :as mat])
(require '[thinktopic.aljabr.core :as imp])

(mat/set-current-implementation :aljabr)
```

I get this error and I can't use the matrix implementation for Javascript

```
INFO: No dynamic loading of implementations in Clojurescript.
You must require an implementation explicitly in a namespace, for example thinktopic.aljabr.core
```

Looking on github I only find the implementation used as I mention above (e.g. https://github.com/mars0i/free/commit/71dbbe4d58645ad4e25f2ac2d4ccba6ccef93968), how can I make aljabr work in cljs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the implementation **statically**, that means not at the beginning of the file like you did but when you actually declare your matrix

```
(mat/matrix :aljabr [[1.0 2.0 3.0][4.0 5.0 7.0]])
```

(I answered to myself just cause there is no result on the internet for that error and took me a while to understand the error message explanation, even with git blames)